# How to Delay Execution of Code For X Amount of Time in Android

Tags: android, xamarin.android

On button click I want to begin a timer of 5 minutes and then execute a method that will check for certain conditions and set off alerts if conditions are right.  I've seen examples with timers and postDelay, but don't really understand why one would use one vs another.  What is the best way to accomplish what I am trying to do?  I don't want to lock up the UI during the 5 minutes.  The user should be free to use the app as normal during the countdown.

EDIT: I am trying the postDelayed suggestion but visual studio is not liking something about my code.  It looks exactly like examples I've found.  My be a mono for android thing.

```
Handler h = new Handler();
Runnable r = new Runnable(){
       public void run()
            {
               Dialog d =  inst2.showBuilder(this, "test", "test");
               d.Show();
            }
        };
h.postDelayed(r, 5000);
```

Specifically the code block inside of run throws all kinds of "} expected" and "a namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods" exceptions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using Timer Object :

```
    Timer mTimer = new Timer();
    mTimer.schedule(new TimerTask()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            // Your code goes here
        }
    }, 1000); // 1sec
```

---

```
    final Handler handler = new Handler();

    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            handler.post(new Runnable()
            {
                public void run()
                {
                    // YOUR Code
                }
            });
        }
    }, 1000); // 1sec
```

Comment: This seems to work ok.  Just have to now figure out how to show an alertdialog if the app is in a context other than the one intiating the timer.  But that is a separate question.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can start a simple `Thread` that will sleep in background for 5 minutes and then call a function. While the thread sleeps in background the UI will not freeze. When the thread finish executing what you want you can set off alerts by sending some intents as notifications and receive them in some `Broadcast Receivers`.
Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Use Handler.postDelayed(Runnable block); method to execute delay, as android also not recommend to use timer.

Answer (score 0):

```
Handler h = new Handler();
Action myAction = () => 
{
    // your code that you want to delay here
};

h.PostDelayed(myAction, 1000);
```